# Is the size of the undo log in InnoDB fixed or does it vary by the size of the iblogfiles? What about redo?

Tags: mysql, innodb

Jeremy Cole's presentation [InnoDB: A journey to the core II](https://www.percona.com/live/mysql-conference-2014/sessions/innodb-journey-core-ii) seems to indicate that there are 128 slots and each slot can have 1024 transactions. So I make that a hard limit of 2^17 updates that are logged in the log files.

I'm looking for a way to rotate out updates from the undo and redo logs in ibdata1 and ib_logfile[01] files. If I can determine - either statically, or dynamically from the configuration - what the maximum number of undo and redo log entries are, then I can force a number of updates into the system that will rotate out the data I'm trying to expunge from the files.

If Jeremy Cole can be taken literally, 131,072 updates should rotate out the original value of a column in a record. Or is it more complicated than that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer is, that it is indeed "more complicated than that", unfortunately. First, some clarifications.

### Redo Log

The "redo log" is configurable via two parameters:

- `innodb_log_file_size` — controls the size of each log file created, in bytes.
- `innodb_log_files_in_group` — controls the number of log files to create, each of `innodb_log_file_size` bytes.

This makes the "log space" approximately `innodb_log_file_size * innodb_log_files_in_group` in size, and you could see, for instance 256 MiB * 2 for a total of approximately 512 MiB of log file.

This redo log space completely allocated at first startup (all files are pre-created at their full size) and is used sequentially from start to finish. Usage of it "wraps around" from the end of the last file back to the beginning of the first, like a circular buffer. Each time a database modification occurs, "log records" describing that modification are written to the redo log. The size of each of these log records is variable.

### Undo Log

The "undo log" is not really configurable and is not really a "log" at all, in the traditional sense. The undo log exists as pages allocated inside the InnoDB system tablespace (usually named `ibdata1`) and consumes its space there. It is not pre-allocated or of a fixed size; it grows on demand. Each time a record is modified in InnoDB, the *previous* version of that record's data is copied into some undo log page before the records in the original page are allowed to be modified.

The undo log pages are each part of a chain of undo log pages which form an undo segment, and consume a "slot" in a rollback segment, which has 1024 slots. There are by default now 128 rollback segments. This is where the mentioned limit of 128 * 1024 (or 2^17) active transactions comes from. Each *active* transaction consumes a slot in a rollback segment, so the maximum number of *active, concurrent* transactions is now by default 128 * 1024 = ~131,072 (however some of those slots are consumed by background tasks, occasionally).

### On expunging old data

The original question was really about how to ensure that data is expunged from the system when the administrator desires it so. This is both very easy and very hard, actually.

Expunging the data from the redo log merely requires that enough redo log space is consumed to completely cycle the redo log. This can be via many small transactions or a few large transactions. Transactions can be executed until the current LSN has advanced by the number of bytes in the log (since LSN is an analog for log bytes, although not perfectly so).

Expunging data from the undo log is nearly impossible, though, and difficult to monitor. There  is no reasonable way to predict which undo segment or undo page will be used for any given transaction, there's no way to see what pages currently exist (or the contents of them) and there is no direct way to influence their destruction. Restarting the server will free the pages for internal re-use, but will leave their contents in place, unfortunately.

Comment: Does shutting down when `innodb_fast_shutdown=0` is in effect cause the undo segment to purge? The manual doesn't say it does, but I often hear "purge" refer to cleaning up undo data.

Comment: @BillKarwin Purging refers to actually deleting delete-marked records from the original pages they were delete-marked in. This occurs with `innodb_fast_shutdown = 0` but the undo logs themselves will still be left containing the old data once the shutdown is complete. The pages will be freed, allowing them to be reused internally, but they will still contain the actual data. So I don't think it does the original asker much good...

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I guess we are assuming the OP's reason to rotate out data is to make sure sensitive data is totally overwritten and can't be inspected?

Comment: @BillKarwin Yes, that's my read on it anyway. He didn't clarify, though.

Comment: @jeremycole Thanks a lot for the detailed explanation. One query, the documentation https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-undo-logs.html states that a transaction can take from 1 to 4 undo logs based on the DML and data (regular or temporary). As you said "Each active transaction consumes a slot in a rollback segment", would you kindly help understand what the documentation is trying to explain? TIA